# I am getting the error at this place 'Countries__r.name' assist me

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am getting the error at this place, with this code:

```
 List<States__c> stat = [select name from States__c where Countries__r.name = :contr];
```

> 'Countries__r.name'

Assist me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this syntax is totally wrong for VFP. Did you really mean VFP?

Your code sounds to be partially C# code against a mySQL database? Not sure. It would error there too. Probably one of those languages that I don't know.

And shooting in the dark, without having an idea on the language you use, you are saying States_c but referring to Countries_r in an SQL?